# Spring SAML - Need two SAML Session and use second session for the approval workflow and not conflict with existing logged in user

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, okta, spring-session

We're implementing SAML2.0 using Apache Tomcat/SAML Security Extension and Okta as IdP. User A logins with the application and spring security context setting the login id as "User A" and when the admin approval needed on few screen, an admin user login with his saml user id/password then the existing session get overwritten.

Needed :

1. If possible the second saml user 'User B' logging in without impacting first logged in saml user "User A"
2. If option 1 is not possible, can i switch between User A Session and User B? i.e After User B work done, can i switch back to User A saml session ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its look like [Spring 2 has retired](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#dropped-support) this feature :(

Any other work around for handling two users on the single browser even one after other without asking for re-login from the user?